# Functions console.log not good

Tags: javascript, function

I came across this exercice on the code academy and I don't understand why my code does not work. can someone explain to me and help me? thank you so much!

1. Here we have a function, addTwo(), that adds 2 to whatever is passed into it. Below that, we’ve created what will be a higher-order function, checkConsistentOutput(). The purpose of the higher-order function will be to check the work of addTwo(). Let’s get started!
   To begin, inside the body of checkConsistentOutput(), declare two variables: checkA and checkB:

- checkA stores the sum val plus 2.
- checkB stores the invocation of the func callback, with val as the argument.

2. Next, below the variables, write a conditional statement that checks if the value of checkA is equal to the value checkB. If true, return the result of the callback function. If false, return the string 'inconsistent results'.
3. Finally, using console.log(), log the invocation of checkConsistentOutput() with two arguments: the addTwo() function and any number.

THIS IS MY CODE:

```js
const addTwo = num => {
  return num + 2;
}

const checkConsistentOutput = (func, val) => {
  let checkA = val + 2;
  let checkB = func(val)
  if (checkA === checkB) {
    return func(val);
  } else {
    return 'inconsistent results';
  }
}

console.log(addTwo(5));
```

I can't pass the number 3 dunno why?

Comment: Where is the call for checkConsistentOutput?

Comment: should I do it like this console.log(checkConsistentOutput(addTwo(5))); ? thank you!

Comment: no.... `console.log(checkConsistentOutput(addTwo, 5))`

Comment: omg... I need to rest... thank you epascarello for the help!!!! I'm still learning around 3 weeks! thank you again!

Comment: You were calling the function and assigning what it returned to the first argument in the function.

Comment: console.log(checkConsistentOutput(addTwo,2));

Comment: Thank you user19139505 I just did the exercice all good! I'm just tired! done for today! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include checkConsistentOutput() in the log, eg:

```
console.log(checkConsistentOutput(addTwo, 5));
```